# How does mic combined with loudspeaker work?

Tags: acoustics

There is variety of loudspeakers on the market that have built-in microphone so that they can produce sound and perceive it at the same time (and do it surprisingly well).

How they managed to overcome audio feedback problems?

[image: example]

Comment: Would [signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) be a better home for this question?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, thanks, done! Should I remove question from this site then? New location: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/how-does-mic-combined-with-loudspeaker-work